# How to use regex in php xpath query ($xpath->query)?

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I would like to search `links` that contain `"click" or "click here"` text as `anchor text`.

If it matches then it should `return href` values.

Can someone tell me how to use `regex` here?

Comment: Can you even use regexes with XPath?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm a noob. Thats why i'm asking this question. It seems like I should use `contains` function. Can you tell me how to use that function to match my text?

Comment: I'm not an xpath whiz, but I think this will work: `//a[contains(text(), "click here")]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use regex with PHP's DOMXPath.  [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) was added in XPath 2.0, but DOMXPath only supports XPath 1.0.

You can try using [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```
//a[contains(text(), "click here")]
```

Comment: Does it also match if the anchor link has the text something like  `click here to visit` ?